# Beamer bullets without itemize

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, bullets

I've been using Beamer for years. On almost every slide I have a `\begin{itemize}` and an `\end{itemize}` and all the `\item Blah` points in between. If there is nesting I need to carefully utilise the same constructs again:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item One
  \begin{itemize}
  \item One and a Half
  \end{itemize}
\item Two
\end{itemize}
```

It occurs to me I could instead use a simpler command which might just insert a bullet point with an optional preceding indent. The output of the code above could be obtained using something like:

```
\i0 One
\i1 One and a Half
\i0 Two
```

I imagine I might easily create such a simple command, perhaps using `\bullet`, but I would rather start by asking: is there something like this already; and has anyone used this idiom for long enough to comment on its pros and cons.

Comment: If this were not beamer, you could use the outline package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\usebeamertemplate{}` macro.  In your case:

```
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}
\usebeamertemplate{itemize subitem}
\usebeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}
```

If you also wish to use their pre-defined colors, you can write

```
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
```

and similarly for `subitem` and `subsubitem`.  Note the enclosing braces to make the color definition local.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\Item}{\par\leavevmode
  \hbox to\labelwidth{\hss\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}\hspace{\labelsep}}
\newcommand{\Subitem}{\par\leavevmode\hskip\leftmarginii
  \hbox to\labelwidth{\hss\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subitem}\usebeamertemplate{itemize subitem}}\hspace{\labelsep}}
\newcommand{\Subsubitem}{\par\leavevmode\hskip\leftmargini\hskip\leftmarginii
  \hbox to\labelwidth{\hss\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subsubitem}\usebeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}}\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \Item One
  \Item Two
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How should I use that? When I insert those 3 lines, either within the preamble, or between the begin/end of a frame,  I get the error: You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode.

Comment: You should add `\leavevmode` in a macro

Comment: I sense this is needing more knowledge of latex than I have. The example you provide has a smaller indentation than we would get with `\begin{itemize}` etc., and so too there is a slightly larger line separation. I didn't know `\usebeamercolor`, so maybe there is a way to get such sizes. But I when I defined `\ItemS`, replacing `itemize item` with `itemize subitem` in both places, I found that this produced no indentation relative to the `\Item`.

Comment: Edited. But I won't recommend to use it.  It is better to use \begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}

Comment: n.b. these bullets won't be aligned with the natural itemize -- to achieve that, I think you need to use `\hskip\dimexpr\leftmargini-\labelwidth-\labelsep` in `\Item`, and something similar for the others