# How to use current \item symbol outside of \itemize list?

Tags: symbols, itemize, bullets

Let's say I have some latex template (using the default `beamer` style here). This template is defining some specific symbol for the `\item`s in the `itemize` environments. Is it possible to use the *same* symbol without using an `itemize` environment?

I'd like this to work independently of the concrete symbol that is being used. For instance `beamer` uses some kind of triangular arrow symbol, while the default `article` uses a bullet point. I'd like to be able to extract the currently used symbol no matter what it is.

E.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item with symbol.
\end{itemize}
I want to use item symbol again here: SYMBOLHERE
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fear there is no simple answer. Classes which use the kernel's list definitions (i.e. standard classes, KoMa, memoir...) define `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, `\labelitemiii`, and `\labelitemiv`. However, `beamer` handles lists differently, and it uses the beamer templates `beamer item`, `beamer subitem` and `beamer subsubitem`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519318

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**
For `beamer` you can access the symbol with `\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}`.

**Long answer**
There is no answer which holds for *any* class. Most standard classes define the macros `\labelitemi`,..., `\labelitemiv`. For example

```
% article.cls ll 533--358
\newcommand\labelitemi  {\labelitemfont \textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii {\labelitemfont \bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\labelitemfont \textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv {\labelitemfont \textperiodcentered}
```

or

```
% scrartcl.cls ll. 6755--6758
\newcommand*\labelitemi{\usekomafont{labelitemi}{\textbullet}}
\newcommand*\labelitemii{\usekomafont{labelitemii}{\textendash}}
\newcommand*\labelitemiii{\usekomafont{labelitemiii}{\textasteriskcentered}}
\newcommand*\labelitemiv{\usekomafont{labelitemiv}{\textperiodcentered}}
```

or

```
% memoir.cls ll. 4711--4714
\newcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbullet}
\newcommand{\labelitemii}{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand{\labelitemiv}{\textperiodcentered}
```

When you start an `{itemize}` environment, the current counter depth is converted to a lowercase roman numeral (from `i` to `iv`) and the corresponding `\labelitem...` macro is used as label for the list. With all these classes you can thus use `\labelitem...` in your document (thought it might be better to add a group around it, lest the font change commands do things you don't want).

`beamer`, however, does things somewhat differently: the counter depth is converted into a string (empty, or `sub`, or `subsub`), and then the corresponding beamer template `itemize XXitem` is used. Therefore you find

```
% beamerinnerthemedefault.sty ll. 173--175
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{default}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{default}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize subitem}\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subsubitem}{default}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize subsubitem}\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
```

A possible workaround is to write in your preamble the following lines:

```
\providecommand*{\labelitemi}{\leavevmode\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\providecommand*{\labelitemii}{\leavevmode\usebeamertemplate{itemize subitem}}
\providecommand*{\labelitemiii}{\leavevmode\usebeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}}
```

In this way, when using standard classes (in broad sense, i.e. also `memoir` and KoMa classes) the `\provdecommand*` will be simply ignored, while using `beamer` it will give the desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive and excellent answer. I thought it would be a little bit easier, but thanks to your answer I understand the issues and how to solve them!